# This code runs on my IDE but not Leetcode which returns "heap-buffer-overflow"

Tags: c

The Leetcode question is "Integer to Roman". Here is my solution:

```
char* intToRoman(int num) {
    char numerals[] = { 'M', 'D', 'C', 'L', 'X', 'V', 'I' };
    int numeral_vals[] = { 1000, 500, 100, 50, 10, 5, 1 };
    int prefix_minus[] = { 100, 100, 10, 10, 1, 1, 0 };
    int arr_len = 7;
    char* roman = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    int romanLen = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {
        while (num >= numeral_vals[i]) {
            roman[romanLen] = numerals[i];
            romanLen++;
            num -= numeral_vals[i];
        }

        int prefixed_val = numeral_vals[i] - prefix_minus[i];
        if (num >= prefixed_val) {
            roman[romanLen] = prefixed_val;
            romanLen++;
            num -= prefixed_val;
        }
    }

    return roman;
}
```

With input of 3 through VS Code, it works. But on Leetcode itself, it gives me a:

```
=================================================================
==34==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60b000000154 at pc 0x562764199bbb bp 0x7ffe8128ec40 sp 0x7ffe8128ec30
READ of size 1 at 0x60b000000154 thread T0
    #2 0x7f53a881f0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x60b000000154 is located 0 bytes to the right of 100-byte region [0x60b0000000f0,0x60b000000154)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f53a9464bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #3 0x7f53a881f0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c167fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c167fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c167fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c167fff8000: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x0c167fff8010: fd fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 00 00
=>0x0c167fff8020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[04]fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c167fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c167fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c167fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c167fff8060: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c167fff8070: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==34==ABORTING
```

After some checking, it seems like mallocing is fine, but I can't return "roman". But what's wrong with that? VS Code handles it just fine.

Also, there's not a tag for leetcode, what can I use instead?

Comment: Is this function expected to return a *string*?  Because it does not provide a string terminator.

Comment: You didn't terminate result string with null character.

Comment: Using `calloc` instead of `malloc` will initialize all of the values to 0 which fixes the termination issue. Still needs some work for a value of 1234 though. https://godbolt.org/z/cErYE56M7 Happy Debugging! You should add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsanitize=address,undefined` to your compile flags in VS Code to help you find issues like this. Pay attention to any warnings you see.

Comment: Please add a [mre] which shows the call of your function.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```c
roman[romanLen] = prefixed_val;
```

`roman[romanLen]`, which is a part of the output string, is assigned `prefixed_val`, which is an auxiliary variable. I don't know this algorithm, but this seems incorrect. Indeed, for the number 4 the function returns a char array holding `4` followed by 99 zeros. The test (I replaced `malloc` with `calloc` in the function to be sure to safely print the whole string):

```c
char *result = intToRoman(4);
for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) {
  printf("%d,", result[k]);
}
```

There are also other problems, as pointed out by [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger), [dimich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14772619/dimich) and [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) in the comments to the question. Remember that `malloc` **does not** initialize the memory (see `man 3 malloc`), but `calloc` does. So, the string `roman` should be explicitly terminated with `'\0'` before doing any operations in which you assume it is a string.

I don't know about the error produced by Leetcode, but maybe this information will help you anyway.

By the way, in the future, you may consider using [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/). It produces quite helpful messages when it comes to handling memory. If you use `gcc`, remember to use it with the flag `-g`. This flag makes Valgrind to add line numbers to its output.